# Remove AMD/ATI Drivers and restore Ubuntu build-in drivers

Tags: uninstall, amd-graphics, gpu-driver

Yesterday I decided to install AMD Ati Driver. My Laptop is with AMD APUs CPU with Radeon R5 build-in. I get to the AMD website and it offered me AMD Catalyst 15.302 driver. During the installation system get me a error message and afterwards I can't go through boot-up screen. It doesn't show at all. I managed to run:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

And now I'm able to log in, but Unity says it's running without hardware acceleration?! And the system feels kind of slow?!
How can I remove AMD driver and bring system back to Ubuntu 16.04 build-in drivers?!